# Element located using xpath in Firebug but execution time NoSuchElementException in Selenium-Java

Tags: firefox, xpath, gmail, firebug

Locating using xpath

but showing exception in  EclipseIDE

WebElement sett = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-tooltip='Settings']"));

sett.click();

[Locating using xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3baM.png)

[but showing exception in  EclipseIDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHskt.png)

.

Answer (score 0):

**NoSuchElementException** happens when the element you're looking up is not present in the DOM at the time of resolution request.  There are typically two causes:

1. Selenium tries to resolve the WebElement before it's visible on the page.
2. Your xpath is wrong

The second one is easy.  Verify your XPath (using a tool such as FirePath).

If your XPath is correct, then it's likely the first.  In which case *WebDriverWait*  or *PageFactory* will help.

*WebDriverWait* is an inline solution to your test that allows the lookup to retry for a certain timeframe before failing.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(dr, 10); //10 second wait
WebElement sett = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@data-tooltip='Settings']"));
sett.click();
```

That should account for the page-load time.

> Note that WebDriverWait will hold for a maximum of the configured
>   time, but can release early if the condition is met!  **Always use a
>   Wait over Thread.sleep**

The second option is a *PageFactory*, which leverages additional features of the Selenium API and a well-defined API to support multiple tests with a common implementation.  This is a very flexible solution for supporting a suite of tests that need to perform common interactions!

```
 public class PageWithSettings {

        @FindBy(xpath="//div[@data-tooltip='Settings']")
        WebElement settings;

        public void openSettings() {
            //Settings will resolve on-demand through the Selenium framework
            settings.click();
        }
    }
```

Then use it in your test(s) for a shared common implementation.

```
public class MySeleniumTest {
        @Test
        public void openSettings() {
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("myPageWithSettings");

            // Use the PageFactory to stand up the reference.
            PageWithSettings pageSettings = PageFactory.initElements(driver, PageWithSettings.class);
            //Call the API method to open the settings page.
            pageSettings.openSettings();
        }

    }
```

---

First, I set up three page factories.

> Email address entry

```
package gmail;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class EmailEntryPage {
    @FindBy(id = "Email")
    private WebElement emailAddress;
    @FindBy(id = "next")
    private WebElement next;

    public void enterEmailAddress(String gmailAccount) {
        emailAddress.sendKeys(gmailAccount);
        next.click();
    }
}
```

> Password Entry

```
package gmail;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class AccountPasswordPage {
    @FindBy(id = "Passwd")
    private WebElement accountPass;
    @FindBy(id = "signIn")
    private WebElement signIn;

    public void enterPassword(String passWd) {
        accountPass.sendKeys(passWd);
        signIn.click();
    }
}
```

> Page that has Settings Buttons

```
package gmail;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class PageWithSettings {
    @FindBy(id=":2m")
    private WebElement settingsDropDown;
    @FindBy(id=":2o")
    private WebElement densityComfortable;
    @FindBy(id=":2p")
    private WebElement densityCozy;
    @FindBy(id=":2q")
    private WebElement densityCompact;
    @FindBy(id="101:settings")
    private WebElement configureInbox;
    @FindBy(id="ms")
    private WebElement settings;
    @FindBy(id="pbwc")
    private WebElement themes;
    @FindBy(id=":2r")
    private WebElement help;

    public void setDensityComfortable() {
        settingsDropDown.click();
        densityComfortable.click();
    }
    public void setDensityCozy() {
        settingsDropDown.click();
        densityCozy.click();
    }
    public void setDensityCompact() {
        settingsDropDown.click();
        densityCompact.click();
    }

    public void configureInbox() {
        settingsDropDown.click();
        configureInbox.click();
    }

    public void openSettings() {
        settingsDropDown.click();
        settings.click();
    }

    public void openThemes() {
        settingsDropDown.click();
        themes.click();
    }

    public void openHelp() {
        settingsDropDown.click();
        help.click();
    }
}
```

I then made a test to verify the interactions:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import gmail.AccountPasswordPage;
import gmail.EmailEntryPage;
import gmail.PageWithSettings;

public class GmailSignInWithSettings {

    private final String MY_EMAIL = "";
    private final String MY_ACCOUNT_PASS= "";

    private WebDriver driver;
    @Before
    public void constructDriver() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void destroyDriver() throws Exception {
        //Sleep call here for demo purposes only!
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSignIn() {
        driver.get("gmail.com");
        EmailEntryPage emailPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, EmailEntryPage.class);
        emailPage.enterEmailAddress(MY_EMAIL);
        AccountPasswordPage passPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, AccountPasswordPage.class);
        passPage.enterPassword(MY_ACCOUNT_PASS);
        PageWithSettings settingsPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, PageWithSettings.class);
        /*
         * Now Do something with the drop-down
         * 
        settingsPage.setDensityComfortable();
        settingsPage.setDensityCompact();
        settingsPage.setDensityCozy();
        settingsPage.configureInbox();
        settingsPage.openSettings();
        settingsPage.openThemes();
        settingsPage.openHelp();
        */
    }
}
```

This seemed to work for me, but I did not test the code thoroughly.  There could be things I'm overlooking.  **Firefox version 45.0.1**

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank You very much for reply Sir. But still with WebDriverWait, and PageFactory it isn't working

Comment: @SagarAjmire I used your sample to recreate the test of logging into gmail and opening the page settings.  Using an updated version of Firefox, Firepath, and Firebug I actually got a different value for resolving the settings button.  I'm adding more content to my response.